# Who said this "suta putra" quote about Karna and what does it mean?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, translation-request, karna

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3MAYwTVDDQ) theme for Karna was used in Star Plus Mahabharata which is in **Sanskrit**. Can anyone tell the meaning of the **Sanskrit** shloka. Also primarily, I want to know where the verse is actually from & who said that?

> Suto va sut putro vayo
>   Vakova bhavamyaham..
>   Daiva yettam kule janm
>   Madayettam tu paurusham
>   Paurusham paurusham..

Comment: Towards the original contents & characters, Star Plus Mahabharata was as honest as Shakuni was during the game of dice!

Comment: @iammilind, we call it megabharata because it resembles mega serials

Comment: What is the meaning of this verse? Is there an English translation or translation into Indian languages?

Comment: It is from [Rashmirathi](http://kavitakosh.org/kk/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%80_/_%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9_%22%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B0%22). It is in Hindi. You can read it or any Hindi users can provide answer after reading it.

Comment: @Rohit. Online sources say, this quote is from that poem. I think we can find it in full version.

Comment: @Rohit. haha.. better not to think y a downvote has been cast or why a VTC has been used :D

Comment: The English translation is “Though am from suta caste but my valour and bravery has nothing to do with it , i'll prove myself with my supernatural skills and abilities”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a play of six scenes called as "**[Veni Samhaara](https://archive.org/details/VeniSamharaBhattaNarayanaDravidK.N._201801/page/n5)**" (Binding-up of the braided hair) written by **BhattaNarayana**.

While discussing about whom to take as SenaPati or Chief Commander:

> Duryodhana told Kripaacharya that Karna is already chosen as SenaPati, so Ashvatthama cannot be chosen.
>
> Then Ashvatthama got little sad and Karna said to him-
>
> Sad people should cry and angry people should take up weapons.
>
> So Ashvatthama got angry and said-
>
> You tell me to cry because I am said. I am not like you who will forget about Shastra-Vidya(knowledge of weapons) because of your Guru's Shaapa(curse). I am from family of warriors and you are son of a weaver.
>
> **Then Karna angrily said-**
>
> I did not leave the weapon from my hand unlike your father who left the weapons in fear of Dhristadyumna.
>
> And also listen,
>
> **सूतो वा सूतपुत्रो वा यो वा को वा भवाम्यहम् ।
>
>   दैवायत्तं कुले जन्म मदायत्तं तु पौरुषम् ॥**
>
> **Whether I am a weaver or whether I am son of a weaver, whoever or whatever I am, this birth in lineage of a family is given by Daiva or Fate. But the Prowess and Power I have accomplished by My Own Self.**
>
> **[Third Scene, VeniSanhaara](https://archive.org/stream/VeniSamharaBhattaNarayanaDravidK.N._201801#page/n206/mode/1up)**

Comment: This is only a play written based on Mahabharata. It needs not be taken for Spiritual understanding. After all, it is only a play, not a religious spiritual Scripture.